# Is there any software to convert carnatic vocal/instrumental music to swaras notation i.e., written musical notation?

Tags: software, classical-music

I want to convert vocal music rendition into carnatic musical notations ( sa re g ma pa ..).

I tried searching for such tools but there are only softwares for western music, where they convert instrumental music to sheet music(musical notations). reference: https://piano2notes.com/ and https://ourpastimes.com/how-to-convert-vocal-music-to-sheet-music-12347617.html

I would like to know if there are carnatic version of such softwares available